# Is there a way to quickly add tags to a question?

Tags: support, tags

Is there a way to just add new tags to a question without having to make an edit?

I think this would be useful for suggesting new or more relevant tags to questions.

Comment: If a question can use different tags, there are normally more things there can be improved on it. Why is this feature (apart from being "useful for suggesting new or more relevant tags to questions") a good thing? That is why is it preferable to proper, full edits?

Comment: I guess that is generally the case, but I think sometimes good questions from newer users not tagging well are being overlooked. A quick way to just add a tag from the question page (either under the question or on the side by "tagged") would encourage users to improve tagging of these questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

> [image]
>
> [image]

However this feature isn't available until you have 10k reputation.

Strictly speaking, this is still an edit, it goes in the revision history, etc., although it doesn't require going to the full edit page.

Comment: Is there any real reason to make this a 10k rep feature? I can edit tags freely at 2k rep, so why wait until 10k to make it easy?

Comment: ^ exactly what I was about to say. But why even 2k? Anyone can edit and add tags, why is high rep required to edit tags quickly?

Comment: @Matt Well, the 2k makes sense, in that suggested edits should generally be substantive, and *most* tag edits tend not to be really substantive; it's likely to be abused more often than it would be useful.  For 2k+ users minor edits are at least less of a problem, even if they're not ideal.

Comment: @Servy but this adds no new power.

Comment: @Cruncher But it would imply that just editing tags makes a good edit.  That's not true of suggested edits.  By and large, if you're going to suggest an edit you should be making a substantive edit to fix up everything that you can.  If all users had access to this feature and started making minor tag edits they'd be confused and upset to find them being rejected as being too minor.