# Is there a way to edit the tags of a question without editing the text of the question?

Tags: support, tags, edits, suggested-edits

Here's a question where the user obviously made a mistake when choosing tags:
[What is this insect in Southeast Idaho?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/70192/1486)

I wanted to change the "etymology" tag to "entomology", but I can't validate my edit: "Edits should be at least 6 characters."

I fail to find the "edit tags" button indicated here: [Is there a way to quickly add tags to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209948/344567)

I'm probably missing the correct way to do this.

Comment: Inline tag edits (the "edit tags" button in the question you linked) are only available to 10k users

Comment: Also related: [Cannot suggest retag-only edit because of subjective title warning(?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303041/295232) – that's why this looked familiar to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have the 'edit tags' button because that requires the [Edit tags inline](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, granted at 10k reputation (2k on beta sites).

You probably couldn't submit the edit because some (less than 6) characters were stripped automatically from the input, which made the server think you edited those yourself. That's a known bug, I'll look for a reference.

What you can do in situations like this: improve the post. The image description (useful for screen readers) could be improved, and I have also resized the image. That's more than enough to get over the 6 character limit.

Comment: I think 2k is enough.

Comment: That's on beta sites, I think.

Comment: I think the "edit freely" privilege is enough.

Comment: Yes for editing tags, but not for *inline* tag editing.